# Cannot zoom out in object mode

Tags: 3d-view

Ok so this problem is a bit weird. In object mode when I start up blender i can zoom out and zoom in but as soon as I add any object be it a light or curve i will no longer be able to zoom out with my mouse wheel. I can still zoom in with my mouse wheel just not out. I can still use the ctrl+mouse click to zoom out but i've gotten used to the mouse scroll zoom and would rather to be able o zoom out with the mouse wheel. Also this only occurs in object mode after i add an object, it does not happen in edit mode or sculpt any other modes. I've tried searching on  the internet bu all the results were about not being able to zoom in.

Comment: what version of blender are you using and on what platform (linux, Windows, mac)? Is this after a recent install of blender of any addons?

Comment: @rob im using the windows version 2.79. I have had blender for quite a while and its only started recently and the only add on i have besides the defaults are the sapling tree thing, but I installed that long before the problem started

Comment: try `File / Load Factory Settings` If that works you can save it as your defaults.